# Internal Server Error - PHP - cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel, directory-listing

I have a PHP site hosted with cPanel.
Yesterday, I changed certain directory listings (using Index Manager). I initially changed the settings from "Default System Setting" to "No Indexing" on all the directories and afterwards I have started getting following error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to     complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@***.*** and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have then reverted all the settings back to their original but still getting the same error.

Following error is shown in Error Log -

```
[Tue Dec 04 01:20:54 2012] [alert] [client 119.226.234.18] /home/***/public_html/.htaccess: ErrorDocument takes two arguments, ErrorDocument Apache configuration directive
```

I don't understand how to resolve this!! Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error in your htaccess.
Open .htaccess in a texteditor. The line with ErrorDocument should look like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html
```

Comment: (and as you see, it should have 2 things after it, where you seem to have only one. Maybe forgotten a space, maybe forgotten the `404`, something like that.)

Comment: How does the problem relate to `404 Not Found` error? A mistake in `ErrorDocument` directive doesn't mean that it *must* be `ErrorDocument 404`.

Comment: Ok, got it!! Thanks, it resolved the issue!!
@Sander Roes - You are a saviour :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue.
By changing the folder permission that I was trying to access to 755 in file manager resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this error log:

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```